# Python: Check where values in a table are in other table

Tags: python

[EDIT] I'd want to solve this problem with Python: I have a table which lists coordinates of some points so it has two columns A, B. An another table lists coordinates of points in two columns C, D. The values in cols C and D are the same of those in A and B, but they are not in the same order. My purpose is to check where a value in A,B is in columns C,D. 
I've tried this code: [Sorry, I put only a part a code, but now it is complete]

```
import pyfits
from nifty import *

hdulist = pyfits.open('PolCat_withRRM.fits')
tbdata = hdulist[1].data


G_lon = np.array(tbdata.field('G_lon'))
G_lat = np.array(tbdata.field('G_lat'))

np.save('glon', G_lon)
np.save('glat', G_lat)

matrix=[G_lon,G_lat]
matrice=np.array(matrix)

#loading information about the sources and the (simulated) data
lon = np.load('lon.npy')
lat = np.load('lat.npy')

#Now I want know where the values in colujmns G_lon e G_lat are in lon e lat columns

delta=(0.003,0.003)
for item1 in zip(G_lon, G_lat):
    for item2 in zip(lon, lat):
        if (item2 >= tuple(np.subtract(item1,delta))) and (item2 <= tuple(np.sum(item1,delta))):
           item2_index=np.where(lon)
           item = lon[item2_index]
           print item2
```

but the output doesn't appear... The code is stuck in the if statement. Can you help me? Thanks :)

The output is an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-eeb8c31b51d3> in <module>()
----> 1 execfile('PolCat_withRRM.py')


 72     for item2 in zip(lon, lat):
 73         #for i in G_lon:
 ---> 74         if item2 >= tuple(np.subtract(item1,delta)) and item2 <= tuple(np.sum(item1,delta)):
 75            item2_index=np.where(lon)
 76            item = lon[item2_index]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in     sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
1833         except AttributeError:
1834             return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 1835                                  out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
1836         # NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
1837         return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.pyc in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
 30 
 31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
 ---> 32     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
 33 
 34 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

 ValueError: duplicate value in 'axis'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure out your code, since it's missing some stuff but for starters maybe try to remove the parenthesis here:

```
if (item2 >= tuple(np.subtract(item1,delta))) and (item2<=tuple(np.sum(item1,delta))):
```

like that:

```
if item2 >= tuple(np.subtract(item1,delta)) and item2 <=  tuple(np.sum(item1,delta)):
```

You don't need for each condition to be inside a parenthesis in python.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it doesn't work. Better, the output is the error I've added in the question..